# What is this tube in a jet engine's air intake?

Tags: jet-engine, feature-identification, inlet, sensors

[image]

[image]

I have long been wondering what is the official name of this little air intake tube located in front of the fan blades and its intended functions. I did search it on google but it was in vain. I guess that it may be a pitot tube installed inside a jet engine for gauging the airspeed of the engine intake air.

Comment: It is not a pitot tube because it is open on both ends, and pitot tubes are only open on one end(with the exception of a water drain hole which is several times smaller than the main opening). It is more of a specialized static-pressure port.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's the EPR inlet pressure sensor (there's another one located aft of the engine in the exhaust).

EPR = [Engine Pressure Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_pressure_ratio), one way to measure thrust.

[image]
([source](http://www.industrial-electronics.com/aircraft_10b.html))

See also:

- [What is the difference between EPR and rotor speed as thrust setting parameter?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32301)
- [How does the EPR reading behave in reverse, and in reheat modes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36951)

Answer (score 1):

One will be the P2 (pressure) sensor, the other will be T2 (temperature)

Comment: This could be improved by explaining the purpose of these sensors.